# Storing checkbox selection in session, Won't let me select nothing

Tags: php, html, checkbox, foreach

Im using this to store my selections of a form in sessions so they can be recalled if the user goes back to another page of the form.

The **problem** i have is it **always has to have 1 selection**. If i tick Jam, then untick Jam and tick butter that works fine, But if i uncheck everything then it doesn't clear the array.

It always has to have at least 1 entry in the array for some reason?

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

This is the `checkbox` **code :**

```
<inputtype="checkbox name="<?php echo $course_menuname."extras[]"; ?>" <?php if(in_array("$extraitems", $_SESSION[$course_menuname.'extras'])) { echo "checked"; } ?> value="<?php echo $extraitems; ?>" id="checkbox">
```

The **variables** are as follows:

> $extraitems contains the "Toast Extras" words, such as Jam, Butter and Flora
>   $course_menuname contains the course such as "breakfast_cereal", "breakfast_toast" then if it has the word extra it does checkbox underneath.

This is the **form :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you explicitly tells PHP to unset the array if $_POST is empty like so

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST))
    unset($_SESSION);
?>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Typically forms do not send data for check boxes that are not checked.  To clear out everything you may just check if there are no values checked and if that is the case clear the session values.  You might try and store these dynamic check boxes in a sub array of the session so that way you can just clear one session variable.  For example:

```
foreach( $_POST as $key=>$val )
{
    $_SESSION[$course_menuname.'extras'][$key] = $val;
}
```

The way you have your form names it will help find these missing values.  You can just do a check if the array element is set for example:

```
if( !isset( $_POST[$course_menuname.'extras' ) )
    unset( $_SESSION[$course_menuname.'extras'] );
```